# Есть ли возможность настроить авторизацию на localhost?

Tags: поддержка, api

Я зарегистрировал приложение, которое хочу проверить на localhost.

С клиента я посылаю следующий запрос:

```
 this.#SE.init({
                clientId: 242321,
                key: 'H4lfg9d-04l3ld',
                channelUrl: 'http://localhost:8888/',
                complete: this.#auth
            });
```

На открывшейся страничке я получаю в адресной строке такой ответ
и ошибку авторизации:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success?assisted=242321&protocol=http&proxy=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a8888%2f#access_token=27(9S5TYEy*Uo6Osm0(9Pg))&expires=86400&state=2
```

[image: ошибка авторизации]

Есть ли возможность настроить авторизацию на localhost ?

Comment: Настройки домена покажите в настройках приложения. Вообще, такое лучше [тут](https://stackapps.com/questions) задавать.

Comment: Я не знаю как туда вопрос перенести сейчас...Мой первый вопрос по авторизации сюда перенесли в своё время.

Настройки приложения.

OAuth Domain
stackexchange.com

Application Website
http://localhost:8888/

true ~ Enable Client Side OAuth Flow

false ~ Disable Desktop Application OAuth Redirect Uri

Comment: Не забудьте сменить key после того как разберетесь с проблемой...

Answer (score 1):

Самый ленивый и простой способ проверить на локальной машине авторизацию использовать  [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Comment: Ну и что это? Там ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: Это ngrok. С ним получилось, что мне требовалось.

Comment: @Qwertiy ngrok - это топовый туннель для разработки. он даже в рекомендованных для azure bot service прописан (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-channel-ngrok?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). А  ERR_CONNECTION_RESET  - это твой провайдер хулиганит :)